# How to display posts from a specific category first?

Tags: wordpress

I tried this...

```
  <?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=9,10'); ?>
```

but now I would like the rest of the posts to display underneath.

Answer (score 1):

You can make something like this to print first one cat, then the other cat, and then the rest of posts. You need to make 3 querys and use the wp_reset_query():

For example:

```
<? */ loop #1 with category ID 9 */ ?>
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=9'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <? the_title(); //just something to print out ?>
<? endwhile; wp_reset_query(); // end loop #1 and reseting query ?>

<? */ loop #2 with category ID 10 */ ?>
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=10'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <? the_title(); //just something to print out ?>
<? endwhile; wp_reset_query(); // end loop #2 and reseting query ?>
```

The result will be a list of post on cat 9, and then a list of post on cat 10. If you need then to print the rest of posts for the rest of categories. Do same thing again, but exclude those cats on the query. That´s puting a "-" on the cat parameter, like so:

```
<? */ loop #3 excluded categories 9 and 10 */ ?>
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-10,-9'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <? the_title(); //just something to print out ?>
<? endwhile; wp_reset_query(); // end loop #3 and reseting query ?>
```

That´s a way, could be many ways for doing same thing, but this is simple to understand.

Hope that helps.